# Why "empty string passed to getElementById()"?

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

So, I have this super weird scenario. Here is how it breaks down. I have different roles for authorization for users to be able to edit a profile in an "Admin Tool". There is one spot of this ability that seems to be acting super goofy, and I cannot for the life of my figure out why! When you are in the role of SuperUsersRole, then the code works fine. But, when you are in the role of StandardUsers role, i get this javascript error and it fails. And, here's another kicker, it ONLY fails when the code is not being run locally. This is written in MVC, so without further ado, here is the code:

the view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ChangeUsername";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeUsername", "User", new { uniqueUserId = @Model.UserGuid }, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "changeUname" }))
{   
<div class="form_section">
    <h3>Update User Name:
    </h3>
    <div class="form_item">
        <div class="frm_label">
            <label for="username">
                @AdminResource.CurrentUserName
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>@Model.UserName</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_item">
        <div class="frm_label">
            <label for="username">
                @AdminResource.UserName
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewUsername, new { id = "uName_change" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewUsername)
            @if (Model.AlternateUsernames != null && Model.AlternateUsernames.Count() != 0)
            {
                    <p>
                        <strong>Suggested usernames:</strong><br />
                        @foreach (var username in Model.AlternateUsernames)
                        {
                            <input type="radio" name="un" value="@username" onclick="setText(this);" />@username<br />
                        }
                    </p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_item">
        <div class="frm_label">
            <label for="password">
                &nbsp;</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Username" class="btn_primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserGuid)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)

}
```

The view model:

```
namespace AdminTool.Models.ViewModel
{
public class ChangeUsername
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameErrorRequired")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "UserName", Description = "UserNameDescription")]
    [NotRegEx(@"^[Mm][rR][Ii]\d{4}|^[mM]\d{6}", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameAlreadyExists")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9!\@#\$%\^&\(\)-_\+\.'`~/=\?\{\}\|]){6,255}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameFormatError")]
    public string NewUsername { get; set; }

    public String UserName { get; set; }

    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }

    public List<string> AlternateUsernames { get; set; } 
}
}
```

And the two corresponding methods in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = Resources.User, Operation = Operations.Edit)]
    public ActionResult ChangeUsername(Guid uniqueUserId)
    {
        User user = UserManager.GetUser(uniqueUserId);
        AuthorizationHelper.ConfirmAccess(Resources.User, Operations.Edit, user);
        ChangeUsername model = new ChangeUsername(){UserGuid = user.Identifier,NewUsername = user.Username};

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = Resources.User, Operation = Operations.Edit)]
    public ActionResult ChangeUsername(ChangeUsername changeUsername)
    {
        User usr = UserManager.GetUser(changeUsername.UserGuid);
        AuthorizationHelper.ConfirmAccess(Resources.User, Operations.Edit, usr);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(changeUsername);
        }
        //setup request
        SupportUser su = (SupportUser)ViewData["SupportUser"];
        RequestData rqd = new RequestData(GetApplicationIdentifer(usr), su.clientIP, su.lanID);
        UserUsernameChangeRequest request = new AdminUsernameChangeRequest(rqd,usr,changeUsername.NewUsername);

        UserUsernameChangeResponse response = UserManager.ChangeUserUsername(request);

        if (response.Status == UserProcessorStatus.Success)
        {
            var message = ("User has been updated successfully");
            TempData["message"] = message;
            return PartialView("_NewUsername", changeUsername);
        }

        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case UserProcessorStatus.DuplicateUsername:
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("NewUsername", "Duplicate username");
                    changeUsername.AlternateUsernames = response.AlternateUsernames;
                    return PartialView(changeUsername);
                }
            default:
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("NewUsername", String.Format("An unexpected error occured. Error Code:{0}, Message:{1}", response.Status, response.Message));
                    return PartialView(changeUsername);  
                }
        }


    }
```

Like I said before, this only happens when you are in a certain role, and when the code is NOT being run locally, which to me is baffling. Thanks in advance!

Edit**
Here is where the console is saying the error is coming from, which is a jquery.unobtrusive.min.js file:

/*
** Unobtrusive Ajax support library for jQuery
** Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*/
    (function(a){var b="unobtrusiveAjaxClick",g="unobtrusiveValidation";function c(d,b){var a=window,c=(d||"").split(".");while(a&&c.length)a=a[c.shift()];if(typeof a==="function")return a;b.push(d);return Function.constructor.apply(null,b)}function d(a){return a==="GET"||a==="POST"}function f(b,a){!d(a)&&b.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override",a)}function h(c,b,e){var d;if(e.indexOf("application/x-javascript")!==-1)return;d=(c.getAttribute("data-ajax-mode")||"").toUpperCase();a(c.getAttribute("data-ajax-update")).each(function(f,c){var e;switch(d){case"BEFORE":e=c.firstChild;a("").html(b).contents().each(function(){c.insertBefore(this,e)});break;case"AFTER":a("").html(b).contents().each(function(){c.appendChild(this)});break;default:a(c).html(b)}})}function e(b,e){var j,k,g,i;j=b.getAttribute("data-ajax-confirm");if(j&&!window.confirm(j))return;k=a(b.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading"));i=b.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading-duration")||0;a.extend(e,{type:b.getAttribute("data-ajax-method")||undefined,url:b.getAttribute("data-ajax-url")||undefined,beforeSend:function(d){var a;f(d,g);a=c(b.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"),["xhr"]).apply(this,arguments);a!==false&&k.show(i);return a},complete:function(){k.hide(i);c(b.getAttribute("data-ajax-complete"),["xhr","status"]).apply(this,arguments)},success:function(a,e,d){h(b,a,d.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")||"text/html");c(b.getAttribute("data-ajax-success"),["data","status","xhr"]).apply(this,arguments)},error:c(b.getAttribute("data-ajax-failure"),["xhr","status","error"])});e.data.push({name:"X-Requested-With",value:"XMLHttpRequest"});g=e.type.toUpperCase();if(!d(g)){e.type="POST";e.data.push({name:"X-HTTP-Method-Override",value:g})}a.ajax(e)}function i(c){var b=a(c).data(g);return!b||!b.validate||b.validate()}a("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click",function(a){a.preventDefault();e(this,{url:this.href,type:"GET",data:[]})});a("form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]").live("click",function(c){var g=c.target.name,d=a(c.target),f=d.parents("form")[0],e=d.offset();a(f).data(b,[{name:g+".x",value:Math.round(c.pageX-e.left)},{name:g+".y",value:Math.round(c.pageY-e.top)}]);setTimeout(function(){a(f).removeData(b)},0)});a("form[data-ajax=true] :submit").live("click",function(c){var e=c.target.name,d=a(c.target).parents("form")[0];a(d).data(b,e?[{name:e,value:c.target.value}]:[]);setTimeout(function(){a(d).removeData(b)},0)});a("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit",function(d){var c=a(this).data(b)||[];d.preventDefault();if(!i(this))return;e(this,{url:this.action,type:this.method||"GET",data:c.concat(a(this).serializeArray())})})})(jQuery);

Comment: Can you post just relevant code regarding your error: `“empty string passed to getElementById()”?`???

Comment: this is the relevant code? it errors on submitting the form to change the username....

Comment: But which line throws this error? Posting rendered client side code would be more relevant

Comment: it throws the error in the jquery.unobtrusive.min.js file.

Comment: it's minified, not sure how to get that to show up correctly on here...

Comment: Does the error occur after the page is loaded following either the GET request, or else following the POST request, or else after the GET request but before the POST request is sent?